# What am I doing Wrong? - Django JSON response and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json, django

I am working on a small website and I need to send thread-post data through JSON.

This is the JSON object django serves:

```
    [{"text":"Some sample text","id":"21","title":"Test Thread"}]
```

I saved this as a .js file and the following Javascript code works fine:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("button").click(function(){
         $.getJSON("testjson.js",function(result){
          $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("div").append(field.text + " ");
          });
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

However when I change the getJSON url field to:

//localhost/wall/21/ - format: //localhost/wall/thread_id

It displays nothing. The web console of firefox does not display any errors either.

My view code is the following:

```
    def thread_view(request, wall, Id):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            thread = api.get_thread(wall, Id)
            if thread != None:
                return HttpResponse(thread, content_type="application/json")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("No results")
        else:
            raise Http404
```

It takes information from the database and formats it into json using a simple serializer, and then sends the data.

What am I missing?

Extra info below...

Serializer:

```
from bson import json_util
class JSONSerializer(object):
    def dumps(self, obj):
        return json_util.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8')

    def loads(self, data):
        return json_util.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

I am using Django 1.6, JQuery 1.1, Python 2.7

P.S
When I enter the following url: 
//localhost/wall/21/ 
firefox displays the JSON object just fine and it's exactly the same as the one in the js file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your `thread_id` contains correct value? Do you add a backslash on the end?

Comment: Yes my thread_id is correct and I do add a backslash at the end. Serverside things seem to be working fine, and when I type the exact same url on firefox it displays the json object correctly, but somehow it isn't working with jquery. Thank you for your comment by the way.

Comment: Try adding error callback and see if there's an error there.

Comment: I added the callback it has an error wen the getJSON function executes, the status code of the request is 0, statusText is 'error' and I cant show the errorThrown parameter, dont know why.

Comment: You might be right, maybe it isn't returning json. I am checking json_util docs but I cant find what the 'dumps' method returns.

Comment: I used python's type() function and the object the dumps function returns is a string (<type 'str'>), does that change anything?

Comment: StatusCode 0 may imply that the request wasn't sent correctly. Does the server side actually receive the request when you send it via ajax? Can you use fiddler or your browser network tab (in Firebug) to see what request is sent and what response is received? And last but not least - are you sending ajax request to the same origin i.e. can it be the CORS issue?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it was a CORS error after all. Made some changes and works like a charm. I really appreciate your help.